# So DataGridView.Rows and DataGridView.SelectedRows return different 'row' types?

Tags: c#, winforms

I had two `foreach` loops in my code. One for all rows in a DataGridView and one for selected rows only. Something like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    //do some stuff here
}
 
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
    //do very similar stuff here
}
```

As both loops did very similar things, I tried to combine them using a ternary condition inside one `foreach`. Both of them have `DataGridViewRow` as their type in their respective `foreach`, it should be pretty simple. I wrote the code as follows:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in allrows ? dataGridView1.Rows : dataGridView2.SelectedRows)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

To my surprise, I got a compiling error saying that there is no implicit conversion between `DataGridView.Rows` and `DataGridView.SelectedRows`, even though we can use `DatGridViewRow` on them separately.
Reading through both properties' documentation on Microsoft's site, they define them both as a collection of rows, so why can't we use them in the same ternary condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reading through both properties' documentation on Microsoft's site, they define them both as a collection of rows

It's because `dgv.Rows` is a `DataGridViewRowCollection` and `dgv.SelectedRows` is a `DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection`. They are thus different and there is no conversion between them (so C# doesn't know which to pick / cannot convert the other one to that), in the same way that you cannot say

```
foreach(string s in someBool ? myStringArray : myListOfString)
```

There isn't a conversion between `string[]` and `List<string>` even though you could happily `foreach(string s in either_of_them_here)`

---

You could cast the contents of each to a consistent form, for example:

```
allRows ? dgv.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>() : dgv.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
```

results in an `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>` no matter which side the ternary picked

---

All in, the return_if_true and return_if_false sides of a ternary must each return types that are the same or be such that there is an implicit conversion from one to the other. For example a ternary of:

```
boolean ? 0m : 1
```

would result in a `decimal`, because there is an implicit conversion from int to decimal, but not the other way around; the integer 1 can be converted to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Each property is of a different type, so a best type for the ternary expression cannot be determined.

One way would be to cast one side to `IEnumerable`, which can then be used as the type of the ternary:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in allrows
    ? (IEnumerable)dataGridView1.Rows
    : dataGridView2.SelectedRows)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

A more readable approach would be to declare a variable before the loop:

```
IEnumerable rows = allrows ? dataGridView1.Rows : dataGridView2.SelectedRows;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
{
    //do stuff here
}
```

The above example uses the improved target-typing introduced in C#9; because `rows` is declared as `IEnumerable` then each side of the ternary is cast to `IEnumerable`.